# How to limit opacity by using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, opacity

I am using an image with dynamic opacity concept, so i used two buttons (+ for increment) and (- for decrement). Actually the opacity working fine but I found some error with limiting opacity value. I want to limit like 0.1 0.2 ... upto 1, but some times it is exceeding and some times it is giving output like 0.8999 0.4000. Can anyone help me.

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <h6>Opacity</h6>
                        <div class="form-group half-space">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon input-xs btn" ng-click="myopacity >= 0.1 ? myopacity = myopacity - 0.1 : myopacity = 0.1">-</div>
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="myopacity" class="form-control input-xs" value="myopacity">

                                        <div ng-click="myopacity <= 1.0 ? myopacity = myopacity + 0.1 : myopacity = 1" class="input-group-addon input-xs btn">+</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: could you reproduce the problem with plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: sorry @PankajParkar  i don't know how to working on it